# new session for every request

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

In my proj there is a requirement that every request should have new session but if  we hit same url in multiple tabs or open same browser twice and hit the url then it is considered as one sessionand we getting inconsistent result.There are some settings in ie browers that resolves my problem but im wondering if we can do it programmatically.Im using struts 1.3.

Comment: Umm ... this doesn't make much sense.  If every request is a new session, you are effectively not using sessions at all.

Comment: I'm not sure you mean what you said; a new session for every request would be useless. Perhaps you mean a new session for each *window*, in which case you'd need to implement some sort of "conversation scope". There are a variety of ways to do so, although I'm not sure how easy it would be to roll them in to Struts 1 since all intra-app links/forms would need to be aware of the new mechanism to distinguish conversations.

Answer (score 0):

I really think that you should take another approach to solve this problem, more on the client side than the server side or maybe mixing both. Off the top of my head I can think on generating a unique ID on javascript each time you load the page (meaning open another tab) and keep this ID as a tab identifier, then you could use these ids on your server side to match the information for each page. Why this should be like this? Because http servers doesn't know anything about browser tabs, they "statelessly" receive requests and send responses and sessions are kind of artificial, they're just tracked by a simple cookie sent from and to the browser which helps the server to know who is talking to.